# How to compare a scalar value with an array in Numba (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numba

How to compare a scalar value with an array in Numba (Python)?
I have a function that has to take 1-D and 2-D arrays as parameters. Within the function I have to check if the actual value for each row is not NaN. I do that with numpy function np.isnan. This function delivers scalars for 1-D arrays and arrays for 2-D arrays. Unfortunately, Numba cannot handle this issue.
How can I check whether a row of an array has NaN values in 1-D or 2-D arrays?
Do I have to write 3 functions: a master function and then delegate to a function for 1-D arrays or for 2-D arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:]), nb.float64[:,:](nb.float64[:,:])], nopython=True)
def is_not_nan_in_array_or_scalar(x):
    result = np.full_like(x, np.NaN)
    is_not_nan = ~np.isnan(x) if x.ndim==1 else ~np.isnan(x.flatten())
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        if is_not_nan[i]:
            # do something...
            result[i] = is_not_nan[i]
    return result

print(is_not_nan_in_array_or_scalar(np.array([1,2.5,np.NaN])))
print(is_not_nan_in_array_or_scalar(np.array([[1],[2.5],[np.NaN]])))
```

This should be the result:

```
[ 1.  1. nan]
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [nan]]
```

This is the error using Numba:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify array(bool, 2d, C) and array(bool, 1d, C) for '$phi50.1', defined at <ipython-input-6-2bd50d9143ab> (6)

File "<ipython-input-6-2bd50d9143ab>", line 6:
def is_not_nan_in_array_or_scalar(x):
    <source elided>
    result = np.full_like(x, np.NaN)
    is_not_nan = ~np.isnan(x) if x.ndim==1 else ~np.isnan(x.flatten())
    ^

[1] During: typing of assignment at <ipython-input-6-2bd50d9143ab> (6)

File "<ipython-input-6-2bd50d9143ab>", line 6:
def is_not_nan_in_array_or_scalar(x):
    <source elided>
    result = np.full_like(x, np.NaN)
    is_not_nan = ~np.isnan(x) if x.ndim==1 else ~np.isnan(x.flatten())
    ^
```

Comment: It works for me on Numba 0.47. What version do you use?

Comment: Rutger Kassies, you have nailed it. I used version 0.45.1 which was not working with Numba decorator. After the update there is no problem anymore. Thank you very much for taking the time and solving my problem.